# c# webbrowser winforms http basic authentication - prompt user to input password

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, basic-authentication

I'm working on a c# webclient using winforms.

I need the webbrowser control to prompt the origin windows authentication popup, when navigating to the page like in IE.

I've already read the solution to build a Popup for getting the credentials. In my case it doesn't work, because it should support multiple servers, which handle the authetication different. Some of them doesn't need the popup - because they handle it on their own way.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: here's the code I use to navigate to the URL:

```
URL = "http://" + UserID+ ":" + Password + "@" + URL;
webBrowser.Navigate(URL);
```

When UserID & Password is empty there should appear the same dialog as in IE to enter the password and user.
Does anyone know, how to force webbrowser-control to show this dialog?

Comment: Was there a question in here? Please give us some code that you believe the problem lies. If it's not in the code then it will be server side.

Comment: The problem seems to be how to indentify if there is need for authentication or not. Windows can not automatically identify for you if a web page needs it or not. Do you have examples of the web pages that you visit?

Comment: A lot more information needed here - "because it should support multiple servers"???